# Trying to set up docker container for postgres

Tags: docker

I just downloaded docker and can't find any documentation to help me with this.

I did

```
brew install docker
```

Then I'm following a tutorial where I'm supposed to do

```
docker pull postgres
```

But I get

```
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

To get the docker daemon running I've tried all sorts of things and keep getting errors.

```
sudo dockerd        
sudo: dockerd: command not found

docker run -p                                                                                      
flag needs an argument: 'p' in -p

docker run -p 8050:8050
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container
```

`launchctl start docker` doesn't fix it.

I'm sure there is some basic command I just have no idea about? Can you please help me.

Comment: can't find any documentation? [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/) is the install guide.

Comment: Thanks but trying any cli commands they have in the documentation gives me the same errors, the daemon isn't running.

Comment: you haven't installed docker correctly yet. so paste the install and service start commands(in any tutorial)  and give output.

Comment: Thanks, my roommate looked and told me I only had the cli commands installed and needed to also install the gui, which I didn't know before. Thanks for helping me.